# Wondering about Acunetix

Tags: security

Does anyone have experience using [Acunetix](http://www.acunetix.com/)?  Is it possible to . . .

- scan/probe all the web sites one has
  open in tabs in a browser? (I know
  there is a Firefox add-in, but I'm
  not familiar with what it does.)
- scan/probe web sites in your browser
  history?

If either is the case, does it follow that one might **accidentally** scan/probe a site based on those or other reasons?

Reading their FAQ and license terms, it seems to me like you need to specifically "nominate" or target a site for scanning/probing.  I certainly had to in the free trial version.  But I don't have the more powerful and perhaps more flexible paid versions, so I'm not sure.  Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply email Laura Hall (lhall at aquion dot com dot au), and ask her for a full-version trial.  I'm sure she'd be more than happy to give you that.

I haven't played with it enough to have anything more to say about it though :)